# Ajax call gives response, but success,complete and error functions not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to get sql results from a database through ajax call and display in another php page. My ajax call is:

```
function newfunc(){
start += 10;
var params = parseURLParams(document.URL);
var datastring = "nextStart="+start+"&subID="+params["hidSubjectID"]+"&topic="+params["hidTopic"];
if(datastring!=''){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax/getTopicQuestions.php",
        data: datastring,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json){ console.log("success"+json[0].question); alert("success");},
        complete: alert("complete"),
        error: alert("error")
    });
}
```

}

My json response has following format:

`[
    {
        "qno": "3",
        "qbit": "(i)",
        "qinstruction": "",
        "question": "This is a  question",
        "mark": "5",
        "examname": "B.Tech. Sixth Semester Examination",
        "examyear": "2011",
        "questionid": "368",
        "examtype": "BPUT Univ Exam",
        "topic": "HTML"
    },...`

This function returns a valid json response (as seen in Chrome DevTools). But none of the `alert()` is executed. But every time console shows `successThis is a  question`. I've scanned through several questions but none seems to resolve this particular issue. I want to display all the data in that json. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That is NOT how you code callbacks

```
   complete: alert("complete"),
    error: alert("error")
```

needs to be

```
   complete: function() { alert("complete") },
    error: function() { alert("error") }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add `function(){}`

```
 complete: function(){ alert("complete");},
 error: function(){ alert("error");}
```

instead of

```
 complete: alert("complete"),
  error: alert("error")
```

Answer (score 1):

callback should be a function.so you need to call a function in callback complete and error or use anonymous function like you did in success callback.

```
 complete: function(){ alert("complete");},
 error: function(){ alert("error");}
```

api Doc: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/